# Can I pass an environment variable to Chef Solo running on a Vagrant VM from my local machine?

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I'm using Chef Solo to set up a Vagrant VM. Is it possible to set an environment variable on my local (host) machine that will be passed to the Chef instance running on the VM?

Comment: What code do you have? What does your `Vagranfile` look like? What kind of information are you trying to pass?

Comment: @sethvargo: I'm trying to forward an environment variable from the host to the VM, so just a piece of text.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question really. Why are you trying to do that? What information does you host machine have that you need to add to your guest? It would be nice to see a `Vagrantfile`...

Comment: @sethvargo: The VM is running a Django dev server that needs to communicate with another server that, in local development, is running on another Vagrant VM. The private IP address exposed for the other VM can be controlled via an environment variable. I want to be able to pass that env var into the Django VM so that the settings file can pick up the IP easily, in a configurable manner.

Comment: @sethvargo: There's really nothing relevant in the Vagrantfile.

Comment: Can I please be the decider of whether your `Vagrantfile` is relevant? I'm happy to help, but this back and forth is a bit annoying...

Comment: Why don't you make it an attribute and then set the attribute in the Chef section?

Comment: @sethvargo: Will that allow individual developers to specify a value on a per-host machine basis?

Comment: Yes. If you set that value to the environment variable... like `chef.json = {'foo' => ENV['YOUR THING']}`

Comment: @sethvargo: Doesn't the Chef client run on the VM itself, though, which won't have that environment variable set? (I gave that a try, but the environment variable was just blank.)

Comment: It does... You aren't passing the environment though - you are setting a Chef attribute to the value of the environment. Remember that file is going to be evaluated...

Comment: @sethvargo: That doesn't really accomplish the goal, but maybe that just won't be possible.

Comment: @sethvargo: Or perhaps it's more of a Vagrant thing than a Chef thing.

Comment: It's relatively easy to read a host's environment variable into your vagrant file with ruby http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ENV.html But I would follow @sethvaro advice on using attributes and have each developer override them in a chef-environment/role attribute but each to their own..